# Loopback Async data call Nodejs

Tags: node.js, loopback

I have method which return list of shows with latest episodes release, which all return total count of episodes. 
I'm kind of stuck at the looping part where i need to count all episodes of  show in the resulted array, as query call are async and i'm unable to syn them. It would great that can suggest solution for this problem

```
server.models.Eps.find({
  include:'show',
  order: 'dateadded DESC',
  limit: 10 },function (err,episodes) {
  if(err)
  { console.log(err);
    return  res.sendStatus(500);
  }
  var show = [];
  var p1 = new  Promise(function (resolve,reject) {
    for(var  i = 0; i < episodes.length;i++)
    {
      var sh = episodes[i].show();
      server.models.Eps.count({'show_id': show.id},function (err,value) {
        if(err) {
          console.log(err);
          return res.statusCode(500);
        }
        console.log(value);
        sh.episodeCounts = value;
        show.push(sh);
      });
    }
  });
  Promise.all([p1])
    .then(function (values) {
      return res.send(show);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to point out here. `show` is defined as an empty array but then the id is referenced in the query `server.models.Eps.count({'show_id': show.id},function (err,value) {`.
I presume that show is a key on the episode data structure so should not be a function call?
Also I'm not sure why you're using `Promise.all` for a single promise.

I think I understand what you're trying to achieve though.

There are a couple of ways you could do this, one which requires the fewest changes and one which would probably be considered nicer.

1. You could use the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library to iterate over the array asynchronously. It should work OK, but it's not very nice to mix callbacks and promises in such a way ( my personal view :) )

   ```
   var async = require( "async" );
   var shows = [];

   async.each( episodes, function( episode, cb ){
     var show = episode.show;
     server.models.Eps.count({'show_id': show.id},function(err,value) {
       if(err) {
         console.log(err);
         cb( err );
       }
       console.log(value);
       show.episodeCounts = value;
       shows.push(sh);
     },
     function( err ){
       if( err ){
         return res.statusCode(500);
       }
       else callback();
     });
   });
   ```
2. The other thing you could do is wrap the `server.models.Eps.count` function in a wrapper that returns a promise. That way you could use a more promise-ish method of dealing with the asynchronous calls. Something like:

   ```
   server.models.Eps.find({
     include:'show',
     order: 'dateadded DESC',
     limit: 10 },function (err,episodes) {
     if(err){
       console.log(err);
       return res.sendStatus(500);
     }
     var promises = [];
     for(var  i = 0; i < episodes.length;i++)
       var show = episodes[i].show;
       promises.push( appendEpisodeCount( show ) );
     }
     Promise.all( promises )
       .then(function( shows ) {
         return res.send( shows );
       })
       .catch( function( err ){
         res.statusCode( 500 );
       });
   });

   function appendEpisodeCount( show )
     var promise = new Promise( function( resolve, reject ){
       var query = {
         show_id: show.id
       };
       server.models.Eps.count( query,function(err,value) {
         if( err ) return reject( err );
         show.episodeCount = value;
         resolve( show );
       });
     });
     return promise;
   }
   ```

Comment: Ohhh!! that was a mistake when  I was creating this code for Stackover flow, correct " server.models.Eps.count({'show_id': sh.id},function(err,value) {".
 As for "Promises.all" there are more promise in above code, just to make  code shorter and fast enough to understand I removed them. I should have added a blank promise to complete the situation.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, Decided to go with second approach